# Parsing time string in Go

Tags: date, go, time

The Spark Rest API returns time in this format: `2016-10-28T16:56:50.497GMT`.

I'm trying to parse that in Go, without any luck. 
I keep getting `0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC`, but the `time.Parse` function doesn't throw any errors:

My function looks like this:

```
func getTime(timeStamp string) (t time.Time, e error) {
    t, e = time.Parse(
        time.RFC3339Nano,
        timeStamp)
    if e != nil {
        fmt.Errorf("Error parsing timestring", e)
    }
    return t, e
}
```

I've tried going through the documentation and created my custom layout, but I can't figure out how I should treat that `GMT` part of the string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to parse that time as `time.RFC3339Nano`, which it is not.

Use the format `"2006-01-02T15:04:05.999MST"`

https://play.golang.org/p/TYHnvclxEn